# I have created SpringBoot project which is not working

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I was following one tutorial to build the project using spring boot. However I am not pro or intermediate in spring boot. So I don't understand when and the problem occurs in my project. I tried to get the solution, but couldn't succeed.

I have attached my code in here:

SmartContactManagerApplication.java

```
package com.smart;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class }, scanBasePackages={"com.smart.*"})
@ComponentScan("com.smart.dao.UserRepository")
public class SmartContactManagerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SmartContactManagerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

User.java

```
package com.smart.entities;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;

//@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String role;
    private boolean enable;
    private String imageUrl;
    
    @Column(length = 500)
    private String about;
    
    //one user can have many contacts
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="user")
    private List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public boolean isEnable() {
        return enable;
    }

    public void setEnable(boolean enable) {
        this.enable = enable;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getAbout() {
        return about;
    }

    public void setAbout(String about) {
        this.about = about;
    }

    public List<Contact> getContactList() {
        return contactList;
    }

    public void setContactList(List<Contact> contactList) {
        this.contactList = contactList;
    }
    
    

}
```

UserRepository.java

```
package com.smart.dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.smart.entities.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

HomeController.java

```
package com.smart.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.smart.dao.UserRepository;
import com.smart.entities.User;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @GetMapping("/test") 
    @ResponseBody
    public String test() {
        
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("Sanket Verma");
        user.setEmail("Sanket@gmail.com");
        System.out.println("Testing");
        
        userRepository.save(user);
        
        return "Working";
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/smartcontact?useSSL=false&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root@123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

Contact.java

```
package com.smart.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;

//@Data
@Entity
(name = "contact")
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int cId;
    private String fname;
    private String sname;
    private String work;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String image;
    
    @Column(length = 1000)
    private String description;
    
    public int getcId() {
        return cId;
    }



    public void setcId(int cId) {
        this.cId = cId;
    }



    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }



    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }



    public String getSname() {
        return sname;
    }



    public void setSname(String sname) {
        this.sname = sname;
    }



    public String getWork() {
        return work;
    }



    public void setWork(String work) {
        this.work = work;
    }



    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }



    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }



    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }



    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }



    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }



    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }



    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }



    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }



    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }



    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }



    //Many contacts can have to one user
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
}
```

The Expected output should be that, the name and email will be saved in database when we run the program.

Comment: What error/output you are getting when you run this command?

Comment: Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Apr 30 09:37:55 IST 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

This is the Error

Comment: I’d start by removing the `.*` from the end of the `scanBasePackages` attribute on `@SpringBootApplication`. As the name suggests, it’s supposed to be the name of the *package* at the *base* of the hierarchy you want Spring to scan for beans. As far as I know it doesn’t support any sort of wildcard. That might explain why it’s not finding your controller class (if that’s indeed the problem).

Comment: So what should I write in here scanBasePackages={"com.smart.*"} ? SHould it be scanBasePackages={"com.smart"} like this. even this is not working.

Comment: That ought to work, although you could also just remove the `scanBasePackages` attribute entirely, because it defaults to the package of the annotated class, which is `com.smart`.

Comment: I removed the scanBasePackages completely, and made like @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class }) this. But getting same error.

Comment: OK, well that eliminates the possible issues that jumped out at me from looking at the code.  If you're still having the issue, can you post the logs from the application and also how exactly you were calling it?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add @RequestMapping on HomeController to identify the resource like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping 
public class HomeController {

...
}
```

Comment: I placed @RequestMapping above HomeController. But still getting same error.

Comment: I did not understand what you said. I tried the @RequestMapping to place above HomeController only. Rest part of the code is as it is.